# How to use edit mode, vertex snap to a edge/vertex/faces group selection in a proper way?

Tags: edges, snapping

I'm a 3ds max user, and there are so very much differences in the way that blender implement the snapping tool.

I wish to know how to make a simple "move-locked parts(polygons, edge, verts) using 3d vertex snap reference from the same object". The major use is to get the same distance between elements.

*As the gif image, I have some segments selected, then I set the distance to zero and set the new one with the below start to end vertex reference...*

[image: As the gif image, I have some segments selected, then I set the distance to zero and set the new one with the below start to end vertex reference...]

It will be very appreciated thanks!

Also I Wanna know If there is a way to make Simultaneous/multi-mesh edge connections - edge loop cuts into a same mesh, maybe discontinuous elements, as the Gif shows:

[image: Simultaneous/multi-mesh edge connections - edge loop cuts]

**Thaks!!!**

Comment: Please keep only one question per post, make as many as necessary. You will find that Blender's snap system is quite limited and inferior in this regard, unfortunately.

Comment: I recommend watching Blender Guru's beginners tutorial, Blender also offers the option to use 3dsmax viewport interactions, you can select that when you open blender

Comment: Sorry for the multi questioning issue, I'm new here as in blender. I've watched a lot of tutorials from paid to free ones, but still difficult for me to understand how'd the snapping goes.

I've try something today, changing the origin point to the selected element and using the snap from element just do what I need, but is a more intricate operation, but you can achieve some similar behavior.